# conda install -c bioconda angsd package not found error

Tags: conda

I've been trying to install angsd as a dependency for another program I'm planning to use and conda install is saying the package is not found when it is in fact a package (https://anaconda.org/bioconda/angsd). I have bio conda as a channel so that shouldn't be the issue. I have tried this in multiple conda versions as I was seeing that this was an issue recently with newer versions. Here is the exact situation that is occurring: 
`conda install -c bioconda angsd`

```
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - angsd

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
(note: had to delete channels due to not enough rep points apparently)

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Any ideas as to why I can't install this package?

Answer (score 0):

The package is only available for linux x64 in that channel, so it cannot be installed for macOS from this channel.

You will have to download and install it yourself. See the [git](https://github.com/ANGSD/angsd) for instructions